# Vinyl Plank Flooring underlayment and backing options

Tags: vinyl-flooring, underlayment

I'm deciding on vinyl plank flooring for a kitchen in a rental property and I'm seeing different options. Cork backing feels incredibly nice under the feet. Other product have a rubber honeycomb backing that doesn't feel as nice under the feet. Even though the cork feels nice under the feet I would imagine if it were to get water seeped through somehow it would absorb the water where the rubber backing may just try itself out. I don't expect it to get wet, but being a rental you never know. I will have a small washer/dryer  that always runs the risk of leaking.

[This is a product I am considering](https://www.flooranddecor.com/rigid-core-luxury-vinyl-plank-and-tile/blonde-oak-rigid-core-luxury-vinyl-plank---cork-back-100378868.html). It has a 22 mil wear layer, cork backing, and is only 5.5 mil thick which I prefer since I'm trying to keep the flooring on the thinner side but have a reasonable wear layer. If getting a product that is 6.5 mil thick is better and will hold together better I will consider a different product though. Is 5.5 mil enough for a sturdy and sound lock?

I'm planning on using a 1 mil underlayment product ([Link to underlayment](https://www.flooranddecor.com/sentinel-installation-materials/sentinel-premium-quiet-underlayment-100893239.html)) that supposedly acts like a sound and moisture barrier, and increases the softness under the foot.

This is on a 2nd floor so the cork backing may add extra sound insulation to the apartment below.

Is cork ideal?

Comment: The ad says the cork is water resistant.  That usually means it can get damp, but a decent leak will ruin it.  The actual floor is water proof, so water should not bother it even with a flood.  Would you even notice the cork backing when walking on the floor?

Comment: cork is meant to get/stay wet, which is why wine uses it and you need to keep the bottle on it's side unless you _want_ the cork to rot.

Comment: Good points to you both. The sales person at the store put some boards down and told me to walk on them. The cork actually does feel different than the other hard plastic backed one. Not sure if that extra cork compression can risk a joint coming apart or not.

Comment: 5.5 and 6.5 *mm* thick, not 5.5 and 6.5 *mil* thick...

Answer (score 0):

I have used that exact flooring in one of my rentals, and similar in a few others. So it's a good idea.

The cork helps with sound and is not likely to get wet if all the flooring is installed properly, ( seams all tight) .  The moisture barrier is not needed since you are on the second floor, but it's your call if you want to add it.

The key here is to get it sealed at the edges so water cannot get under it.
That means in any area where water may get in the floor caulk the baseboards to the floor and the toe kick under the cabinets.  Then if a pot of pasta waster is dropped or someone overflows the sink the water cannot seep back under the edge of the flooring.  (My wife calls it "tenant proofing")

Also some manufacturers say you cannot place cabinets directly on the product, but I can tell you from a decade of experience that you can without any issues.
Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @RMDman.  I figured I'd use that underlayment as 2 extra mm of sound dampening and possible help if there are slight dips in the floor in certain places.  I didn't realize people caulk the edge but it makes sense in problematic area. Your input is appreciated and valuable, thank you.